# cmake version in catkin_make different from global cmake version?

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I'm trying to build some package in ROS using catkin.

When I run catkin_make in the top level directory, I got complaint about cmake version:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/ignition-math4/ignition-math4-config.cmake:26 (cmake_minimum_required): 
CMake 3.5.1 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.3.2
```

Then I updated my cmake version, and also modified the path. I verified that the version of cmake is now 3.15:

```
~/catkin_ws$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.15.0
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

when I go back and try catkin_make again, the problem still remains.

I suppose that catkin has defined its own path or environment variable somewhere and are using cmake from a different place, but I couldn't figure out how to change it. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

--Kevin

Comment: did you ever find a solution? i'm on the same situation

Answer (score 1):

you could remove `.catkin_tools` from your working directory, and redo the initialization of catkin:

```
source /opt/ros/<your-ros-development>/setup.bash
```

and

```
catkin init
```

if your environment setup is correct, that should do the trick.